# If nmap reports a port is open, does that ALSO mean a service is listening on the port?

Tags: networking, router, firewall, port, nmap

I have a Thompson TG585v7 router/firewall whose firewall is configured to `FORWARD`  several ports to a computer `X54` within the LAN.

These ports are in the range `1024 through to 2500`

That `X54` computer is now gone and so there is nothing "listening" on those final destination ports

If I use scan the firewalls public IP using

```
nmap -O -p 1000-2500 219.xxx.xxx.xxx
```

It reports other fully functioning ports that are open and have a service listening, but doesn't show these ports that are forwarded to a non-existant machine.

So My question is, if `nmap` reports that a port is "open", does that both these conditions have to be true.

1. the firewall is accepting connections on the given port
2. there is a machine/service listening on the other end?